# Android add ImageView programmatically

Tags: android, imageview

I currently add images through xml with the whole **R.id.x** method with the following function:

```
public void Image(int ID, int x, int y){
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(ID);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    position.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);

    iv.setLayoutParams(position);
}
```

I've written a new function to get these images on screen programmatically instead of parsing them in XML, with help from afore-mentioned topics/questions I searched and came up with this:

```
public void ImageRAW(int ID, int x, int y){
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(c);
    iv.setImageResource(ID);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    position.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);

    iv.setLayoutParams(position);
    rl.addView(iv);
}
```

But it did not work. I also tried adding the following line, to no avail: **iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);**

And in regards to the variables ***rl*** and ***c***:

```
private Context c;
private RelativeLayout rl;

public void SetUtilContext(Context context){
    c = context;
    rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
}
```

The above function is called in every Activity's *onCreate()* function and sets the UtilLib's current Context and RelativeLayout for drawing accordingly.

The function ***ImageRAW()*** is something I would like to use to replace the old ***Image()*** function, to make things easier for me. How would/could I get this working?

Comment: I hope ID in findViewById() method is not the same as ID in setImageResource() method. Image's ID should be R.id.x and ImageRAW's something like R.drawable.x

Comment: You've created a RelativeLayout, but is it part of the screen content?

Comment: @Incredible Yes, for the ImageRAW function I supply a R.drawable.x

Comment: @Karakuri the RelativeLayout is part of the accompanied XML file, which is set as the current view in the onCreate() function.

Comment: can u show us your onCreate method?

Comment: I'll post it in an answer, as my onCreate() is too large by.. 400 characters for a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add this before your SetUtilContext():

```
RelativeLayout menu = findViewById(R.layout.menu);
```

And this at the end of your ImageRAW() method:

```
menu.addChild(rl);
```

Comment: Your approach worked, but I had to tweak it by a small margin.

    ImageRAW(R.drawable.head, R.id.game, 250, 100);
This because I'm using a tabhost, so giving a layout as a direct parameter won't work; so the id of the layout has to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

As per Incredible's request, my onCreate function where I'm testing the functions:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    SetUtilContext(this);
    Image(R.id.logo, 0, 0);
    GetScreenSize();

    ImageButton(R.id.start_btn  
                , (screenWidth/2)-(GetImageWidth(R.id.start_btn)/2)     
                , 48+GetImageHeight(R.id.logo));
    ImageButton(R.id.options_btn
                , (screenWidth/2)-(GetImageWidth(R.id.options_btn)/2)   
                , 96+GetImageHeight(R.id.logo)+GetImageHeight(R.id.start_btn));
    ImageButton(R.id.about_btn  
                , (screenWidth/2)-(GetImageWidth(R.id.about_btn)/2)     
                , 144+GetImageHeight(R.id.logo)+(GetImageHeight(R.id.start_btn)*2));
    ImageButton(R.id.exit_btn   
                , (screenWidth/2)-(GetImageWidth(R.id.exit_btn)/2)      
                , 192+GetImageHeight(R.id.logo)+(GetImageHeight(R.id.start_btn)*3));
    PlayAudio(R.raw.theme, true);

    ImageRAW(R.drawable.head, 0, GetImageHeight(R.id.logo));
}
```

Comment: You are creating new RelativeLayout, creating new LayoutParams for it, adding image into this RelativeLayout, but I can't see where you add this RelativeLayout to your activity.